# Intel Software Raid: Downgrade from RAID10 to RAID 1

Tags: hard-drive, raid, intel-rst

### My configuration

- Windows 8.1
- [Asus Z87I Pro (Rev C2)](http://www.asus.com/de/Motherboards/Z87IPRO/)
- 4x WD Red 3TB, set up as RAID10 in the Intel tool / EFI

### My target

- I want to remove 2 of the HDDs permanently from the RAID because I don't need that much space anymore. The Raid should be RAID 1 afterwards (mirroring)
- None of the discs is faulty.
- I don't want to re-install Windows 8.1, obviously.

### My question

- What do I have to do to downgrade this RAID10 to RAID1, such that I will be able to remove 2 of the 4 HDDs afterwards?

Comment: What you want is technically not possible, you would have to copy all your data, and then restore the data on the new raid to do what you want.  You can't simply change the RAID configuration in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to just "switch" RAID modes like that, as the array would need to be recreated/reinitialized.

Easiest:

- Reduce data so it's small enough to fit on the RAID1.
- Get an external drive that's large enough to accommodate your data (and then some).
- Perform full system backup to external drive.
- Destroy RAID10.
- Remove 2 drives.
- Create RAID1.
- Restore Backup from external.

If you can't obtain an external drive (aka: "slow, nitpicky, dangerous way"):

- Reduce data so it's small enough to fit on the RAID1.
- Determine which drives (by serial number, etc.) are in which part of the RAID10, and pull the two you can afford to loose (that won't bring the array down).
- Create an additional array that's RAID1, using the two drives you detached from the RAID10.
- Perform full system backup from degraded RAID10 to healthy RAID1.
- Destroy RAID10.
- Create RAID1 with two drives that were last in RAID10.
- Restore Backup from first RAID1 you made.
- Destroy RAID1 you first made.
- Remove 2 drives.

Note: Have RAID controller drivers available on USB at all times.